# How do I prevent a ListView header from obscuring the top of the first group?

Tags: delphi, listview, delphi-xe

I use Delphi XE and I want to make a standard ListView behave and look like I want it. 
I want the listview to be vsReport so I can have Groups for my items.
At design time I created the columns (one column named Topic), two groups, and a few items for each group.

At design time the ListView looks great, but at runtime, my first group is somehow partially hidden under the column caption. Here are the images:

*At designtime:*

[image]

***At runtime:***

[image]

and here is my DFM

```
object Form2: TForm2
  Left = 326
  Top = 150
  Caption = 'Form2'
  ClientHeight = 636
  ClientWidth = 1289
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object ListView1: TListView
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 205
    Height = 636
    Align = alLeft
    Columns = <
      item
        Caption = 'Topic'
        Width = 200
      end>
    ColumnClick = False
    DoubleBuffered = True
    FullDrag = True
    Groups = <
      item
        Header = 'First group'
        GroupID = 0
        State = []
        HeaderAlign = taLeftJustify
        FooterAlign = taLeftJustify
        Subtitle = 'Options bellow'
        TitleImage = 1
      end
      item
        Header = 'Settings'
        GroupID = 1
        State = [lgsNormal]
        HeaderAlign = taLeftJustify
        FooterAlign = taLeftJustify
        Subtitle = 'Other options here'
        TitleImage = 0
      end>
    HideSelection = False
    HotTrack = True
    HotTrackStyles = [htUnderlineCold, htUnderlineHot]
    Items.ItemData = {
      059E000000030000000000000000000000FFFFFFFF0000000000000000000000
      000A4600690072007300740020006900740065006D000100000001000000FFFF
      FFFF0000000000000000000000000B5300650063006F006E0064002000690074
      0065006D000200000002000000FFFFFFFF000000000100000000000000134600
      69007300720074002000730065007400740069006E0067007300200069007400
      65006D00}
    GroupView = True
    RowSelect = True
    ParentDoubleBuffered = False
    ShowWorkAreas = True
    TabOrder = 0
    ViewStyle = vsReport
    OnClick = ListView1Click
    ExplicitTop = 8
    ExplicitHeight = 497
  end
end
```

How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is present even in Delphi 10 Seattle. I'm not sure what causes it but you can work around it by making a significant change to the list view properties, and then reverting that change. That seems to be enough to get the list view to catch up. For instance, this will suffice:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListView1.ViewStyle := vsIcon;
  ListView1.ViewStyle := vsReport;
end;
```

But that's somewhat over the top. Digging in to what effect this code has, the key thing it does it to recreate the window. Which can be done like this:

```
type
  TProtectedHackListView = class(TListView);

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TProtectedHackListView(ListView1).RecreateWnd;
end;
```

Or even recreating the form, which in turn will recreate the children:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RecreateWnd;
end;
```

Comment: The `RecreateWnd()` on just the `TListView` would suffice. Changing the `ViewStyle` is overkill, as is recreating the Form's window and all of its child controls.

Comment: Thank you both. Remy Lebeau, your comment was very helpfull too. Thank you

Comment: As a test, I created a `TForm` whose `CreateWnd()` method directly calls the same APIs that `TListView` does, and the resulting ListView does not exhibit the problem. Very odd.  Maybe there is something extra `TListView` is doing to confuse the underlying window in how it manages its content in relation to its built-in header control.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Changing the view style is a way to avoid the somewhat hacky call to the protected method.  And it was the first thing that I tried that worked.  It does the trick because it recreates the window handle ......

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yes, it does recreate the window - twice, and also does a lot of unnecessary work to setup the icon view just to tear it down to setup the report view again. Better to just recreate once and let it setup the existing view.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I agree. I mostly included that because it was how I discovered the workaround. I'm sure the asker will be able to choose the right solution.